# AngularJS - Remove leading and trailing whitespace from input-box using regex

Tags: regex, angularjs, html

I am writing a regular expression(regex) for adding multiple email ids in an input box with following conditions:

1. Multiple email ids must be separated with comma `,`
2. Need to have atleast one email id
3. There should not be any whitespaces in input field.

So i created this regex:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([,.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$
```

I tested it in regex101.com and its working like a charm https://regex101.com/r/bU7rU8/1

But when i integrate it with code, it works, **but fails on leading and trailing whitespace**.

Here is the demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/2G8gA/330/

Comment: Use `ng-trim="false"`. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltpo2wL5/). Is it what you need?

Comment: @stribizhev: You made my day. I am struggling to find out the issue from last 2hrs. Thanks for help. Please post an answer. I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AngularJS trims the input by default, so you need to use `ng-trim="false"` in order to pass leading and trailing whitespace to your `pattern` regex.

See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D):

> **ngTrim** (optional)
>
> If set to `false` Angular will not automatically trim the input. This parameter is ignored for `input[type=password]` controls, which will never trim the input.
>
> *(default: true)*

Answer (score 2):

Do you want leading/trailing spaces allowed on the whole string, or around each individual address?

For the former your regex should be

```
/^(\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([,.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+\s*)*$/
```

and for the latter

```
/^(\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25}\s*)+([,.](\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+\s*)*$/
```