# I need a regular expression to remove white space in the beginning and it should allow spaces in between two words

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Here is my source code. I have written a directive in angularjs to eliminate spaces. It's perfectly working for spaces between words but is still allowing spaces at the beginning.

```
function customValidation() {

   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

         var transformedInput = inputValue.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,''); 

         if (transformedInput!== inputValue) {
           modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
           modelCtrl.$render();
         }         

         return transformedInput;         
       });
     }
   };
}
```

Comment: Set `ngTrim` to `false`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32135166/3832970

Comment: I have already set the value ngTrim to false.. <span.... custom-validation ng-trim="false" required>

Comment: I suspect you just want `.replace(/\s+/g,'');`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , Martin already answered it !

Comment: @TilakMadichetti: How? Find 1 important difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove whitespace just from the *beginning*

```
inputValue.toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Hi martin, thank you,your example is working for me but my case it should not allow spaces on the beggining and it should allow only one space after a word. but the regular expressiion you have given is accepting more white space after a word. If you have any ideas to eliminate more spaces after a word please share thanks...

Comment: In the context of the current approach, `/g` is totally meaningless here. How many starts of the string can there be in a string? Yes, 1.

Comment: @VarathanSwaminath - sure, updated to remove multiple spaces between words. Wiktor - good point!

Comment: @martin thanks a lot it worked... :)