# Angular ng-pattern regex not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I'm trying to create a validation for an angular input field which accepts only the a-zA-Z0-9 characters and special characters ".”(full stop), "_" (underscore), "@"(at sign)

I can't seem to get the hang of it.

I tried:

```
ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9_@.]+/"
```

requirement:

- It can contain only alphabetic characters
- it can contain alphabetic and numeric
- It can contain alphabetic numeric and mentioned special characters
- It cannot contain space

Comment: Why do you have `!` in it?

Comment: Your regex is correct other than the `!`. What inputs are being accepted/rejected that you don't expect? Show sample inputs and results and indicate the ones that don't fit expectations.

Comment: but does not allow only alphabetic

Comment: Yes, it does: https://jsfiddle.net/e9qc681e/  `console.log(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@._]+$/g.test("abc")); // true`

Comment: Does not work with angular - ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9@._]+$/g"

Comment: Well, that was information that was useful to put in the question. Along with an [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I notice that [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) says not to use the `g` flag.

Comment: try with `ng-pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_!@.]+"`?  I think that if it's a string the ^ and $ are added implicitly based on [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern).

Comment: @LukStorms: Not working with ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9_!@.]+/"

Comment: and without the `/` ?

Comment: @LukStorms without / - error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$parse/lexerr?

Comment: The documentation doesn't seem to show an example of an ng-pattern with regex that's not put in a string. But maybe you could test it anyway with `ng-pattern=/^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.]+$/` ?

Comment: Works fine over here: https://plnkr.co/edit/lhkmD4UbR0aqEUofCUjD?p=preview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ng-pattern should be as follows:

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.]+$/"
```

See demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ElBuuxGilBbC9fdA2n0P?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

This will work for you..
 ng-pattern= "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._@]+$/"

Answer (score 3):

Here are the "blocks" to write the final solution:

> It can contain only alphabetic characters - **Use `^[a-zA-Z]+$`**
>   it can contain alphabetic and numeric - **Use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`**
>   It can contain alphabetic numeric and mentioned special characters - **Use `^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.]+$`**
>   It cannot contain space - **Use `ng-trim="false"` (see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135035/angularjs-remove-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-from-input-box-using-regex/32135166#32135166))**

JS full demo:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form">
    <p>Enter text to validate:</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.]+$/" ng-trim="false" />
    <div ng-show="form.name.$error.pattern">Text doesn't match with ng-pattern!</div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add up to date information. If you use Angular4 it should be:

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.]+$"
```