# Why does password fields in admin console of Keycloak removes spaces in beginning and end of the password i entered

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, keycloak, keycloak-services

I want to show an error message when the admin entered spaces either in beginning or end of the password fields. But i noticed that the returned password when i click the reset button automatically removes the whitespaces in beginning or in the end of the string. Only the spaces in between are detected.

[image: Here is the keycloak Admin Console UI]
I did an inspect element on the pw fields and i saw this lines.

```
<legend><span class="text ng-binding">Manage Password</span></legend>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label ng-binding" for="newPas">New Password


<span class="required ng-hide" data-ng-show="create">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

<input class="form-control password-conceal ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse 
ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" kc-password="" type="text" id="newPas" 
name="newPas" data-ng-model="password" required="">
```

But when i search it on the keycloak files i saw they are different.

```
<legend><span class="text">{{:: 'manage-user-password' | translate}}</span></legend>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="newPas">{{:: 'new-password' | translate}} 

<span class="required" data-ng-show="create">*</span></label>
<div class="col-md-6">

   <input class="form-control" kc-password type="text" 
id="newPas" name="newPas" data-ng-model="password" required>
```

Here is the full html file: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/admin/resources/partials/user-credentials.html

And here is angularjs code that it uses:

```
$scope.resetPassword = function() {
        // hit enter without entering both fields - ignore
        if (!$scope.passwordAndConfirmPasswordEntered()) return;

        if ($scope.pwdChange) {
            if ($scope.password != $scope.confirmPassword) {
                Notifications.error("Password and confirmation does not match.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var msgTitle = 'Change password';
        var msg = 'Are you sure you want to change the users password?';

        Dialog.confirm(msgTitle, msg, function() {
            UserCredentials.resetPassword({ realm: realm.realm, userId: user.id }, 
{ type : "password", value : $scope.password, temporary: $scope.temporaryPassword }, function() {
                    Notifications.success("The password has been reset  test"+$scope.password); 
//here i confirmed that the returned password automatically removes the spaces in beginning and end. 
Only spaces in between are accepted.


                        $scope.password = null;
                        $scope.confirmPassword = null;
                        $route.reload();
                    });
                }, function() {
                    $scope.password = null;
                    $scope.confirmPassword = null;
                });
            };

            $scope.passwordAndConfirmPasswordEntered = function() {
                return $scope.password && $scope.confirmPassword;
            }
```

Here is the full js scripts: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/admin/resources/js/controllers/users.js

Please help me to locate how does keycloak removes the spaces i entered in beginning or end of the password! thanks

[image: Here i displayed the password returned no spaces even i input spaces at the beginning :]

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
For reference: [AngularJS - Remove leading and trailing whitespace from input-box using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135035/angularjs-remove-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-from-input-box-using-regex)

Angularjs by default uses ng-trim = true in password fields. 
So i set the password input to ng-trim = "false" and it worked!